# Need help to run BIMSurfer without running BIMServer

Tags: ifc, bim

I need to run BIMSurfer over nginx without running BIMServer. As I noticed, BIMSurfer needs some js files that takes them from BIMServer. I don't need BIMServer to handle ifc files which I convert them beforehand.  I looked into [this link](http://aecgeeks.com/viewer/) and thinking of something akin.

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact question? If you are looking for the way to convert I suggest IfcOpenShell to generate dae, obj or gltf files. To render the converted ifc file, you can implement your own viewer, or use the BIMSurfer directly. If I remember correctly, gltf format works fine with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
1- I want to know how to implement BIMSurfer. 
2- Another interesting thing is making my own viewer. 
Appreciate your help.